# Play services 11.6: OAuth consent screen not showing when published

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-drive-android-api

Despite having copied the code from the official sample app, authentication consent screen is not showing when app is released through Play Store. I have properly generated two OAuth 2.0 credential on Google Api Developer Console, one for release (using my private keystore) and one for debug (using Android Studio debug keystore).

UPDATE: installing my app on an older 4.4 emulator in debug mode I noticed the same behavior of the release app on newer devices. No consent screen appears, and Logcat shows this message:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   11717000 but found 11509030

Could it be that newer [GoogleApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi) interface fails to prompt the user to install/update PlayServices, even if the official documentation says that?

**Here is my code:**

***build.gradle (app)***

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0'
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

***DriveActivity.java***

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0;

protected GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
protected DriveClient mDriveClient;
protected DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;

protected abstract void onDriveConnected();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> getAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    if (getAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                        initializeDriveClient(getAccountTask.getResult());
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Sign-in failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void signIn() {
        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.getGrantedScopes().contains(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)) {
            initializeDriveClient(signInAccount);
        }
        else {
            GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
            startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
        }
    }

    private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this, signInAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, signInAccount);
        onDriveConnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question. The problem is that Google Play Services is not updated, and the recent GoogleApi interface does not check for that (a bug, maybe?).
So you have to put a check before trying the authentication:

```
protected void signIn() {
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        ...
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.message_unsupported_device, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: If you pass an Activity to GoogleSignIn.getClient(), you should see a dialog prompting for Google Play services update.  Could you try on a physical device? For emulators without Play Store, behavior is slightly different (i.e. unrecoverable error which show up in logs only).

Comment: Hmm... that's not expected. getClient(Activity, options) should trigger a dialog if Google Play services is older than SDK. So what you pasted for DriveActivity.java is direct copy from your Activity code? And your physical device has older Play services than 11.6?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I solved it only by checking play services explicitly before...

Comment: I see. Are you targeting api level 26? There's a known issue with that combination.

Comment: Yes, targetSdkVersion is 26.

Answer (score 0):

For other people, GoogleSignIn.getClient(this /* activity */, signInOptions) should usually auto-prompt for Play services update if needed.

But in newest 11.6 SDK, this feature is temporarily broken with targetSdkVersion 26. Consider using GoogleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment() under these conditions for now until the fix it out in future releases.